# How to execute external command in jenkins which in docker

Tags: django, docker, jenkins

I pulled the official jenkins from dockerhub and run it with: 
`docker run --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/www/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -u root jenkins`

And then I added new execution shell in build:

```
python3.6 manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

But it inform me that "python3.6" not found in build result. Is there any way to execute external docker command? Or what's the best practice for django + jenkins in docker?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the python3.6 is not in the `$PATH` environment variable.

You have to replace the python3.6 with the absolute path

`/usr/bin/python3.6 manage.py collectstatic --noinput`

Comment: there is no python3.6 in docker

Comment: you have to install it them before executing a command inside the container.

There are two options, 1) create new Dockerfile based on jenkins image
2) login inside the container and install python `docker exec -it jenkins /bin/bash`